# Angular post to nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angularjs

I just wanna post some changes to the database. This is my angular - the problem is, it dosn't take values from my html inputs.

See section 2 of code:

```
mainController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.post = {};
    console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.post);
    $http.get('/api/todos')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data.posts;
            $scope.datas = data;
            // console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

    $scope.editTodo = function() {
        console.log($scope.post);
        $http.post('/post/edit', $scope.post)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.post = {};
                console.log($scope.post);
                $scope.posts = data.posts;
                $scope.datas = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
}
```

Section 2:

```
 <div class="comment" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search:strict | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <div class="comment-content">
          <form>
            <input type="text" class="" ng-model="post.id" />
            <input type="text" class="h2" ng-model="post.title" />
            <textarea ng-model="post.content" ></textarea>
            <span class="submitcontent" ng-click="editTodo()">
              Submit
            </span>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I don't get why my `$scope.post` obj is allways equal to: `Object {}` and my log from the node server shows:

```
{ id: undefined, postTitle: undefined, postContent: undefined }
POST /post/edit 200 8ms - 2.92kb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ng-repeat` directive `post` is the current post **NOT** `$scope.post`. Just pass the post you're dealing with to your edit function:

```
<span class="submitcontent" ng-click="editTodo(post)">Submit</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.editTodo = function(p) {
    console.log(p); // will have your id, title and content.
};
```